# Which 3 points are best to get a good floor? (Motion tracking)

Tags: camera, tracking, motion-capture

When I set the floor of my tracking scene,  I have to select 3 points to use. However, I noticed that the orientation changes depending on which 3 points I pick. I always thought it didn't matter. But that begs the question, which 3 points work best? Here are some pictures showing the situations.

As shown in the pictures, different points give different results, of which some work better than others. How should I know which 3 points to use in a scene not as controlled as this? This is not a subjective question directly relating to this scene, it is so that I know which points are supposed to be used, as there is a right and wrong answer.
[image]

[image]

[image]

The 3 selected trackers are the ones used to set the floor, and you can see using the y axis that the position and orientation changes.

Comment: I will check that tomorrow for curiousity ... But from your screens you can see one of them represents world origin, and one x axis ... Did you setup also y axis and x axis ... The buttons bellow Floor,Wall?

Comment: No, but those make the results worse. The only thing I did use was origin. But notice how it doesn't only affect orientation, but offset as well.

Comment: What is your Average Projection Error? You are placing Tracker at center of marker ... should be at edge or used some smaller point to prevent sliding.

Comment: Its 0.13 pixels, not that big as I used focal length k1 -k2. Before I used focal length it was 1.5 I think.

Comment: Hard to guess based on the provided screenshots. I'd recommend add a blend file along with the footage. I suppose that there is something wrong with some of the trackers on the ground since their movement over time is way too different.

Comment: How would I share the image sequence?

Comment: I also had this problem.  I just used any three, and rotated the whole of scene manually later.   By the way, the markers in your images are not high quality.  This might cause some precision problem.

Comment: So I guess there is no right answer :\        Well, thanks for the advice

Comment: There is an answer, more details are required though (as requested already).

Comment: @brockmann OP was already asking ho w to share, but nobody answer that ... with image sequence I'm not sure ... it seems like it is not possible pack into blender, right? With tracker issue I thought the same, but error is just 0,13 ...

Comment: @Relevred for sharing blend you can use https://blend-exchange.com movie or image sequence is not probably possible to pack with blend ... so you would have to use some external links

Comment: @Relevred it is possible to pack image sequence in to .blend. go to file> external data>pack all into .blend. this should pack all the extra things to the .blend file